# How to conditionally buffer RACSignal values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm working on some code that interacts with a remote API via websockets.  My data layer is responsible for establishing and monitoring the websocket connection.  It also contains methods that can be used by the application to enqueue websocket messages to be sent.  The application code should not be responsible for inspecting the state of the websocket connection, aka fire-and-forget.

Ideally, I'd like to data layer to function as follows:

- When the data layer does not have a connection to the websocket endpoint (`self.isConnected == NO`), messages are buffered internally.
- When a connection is becomes available (`self.isConnected == YES`), buffered messages are immediately sent, and any subsequent messages are sent immediately.

Here's what I've been able to come up with:

```
#import "RACSignal+Buffering.h"

@implementation RACSignal (Buffering)

- (RACSignal*)bufferWithSignal:(RACSignal*)shouldBuffer
{
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {

        RACCompoundDisposable *disposable = [RACCompoundDisposable compoundDisposable];

        NSMutableArray* bufferedValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        __block BOOL buffering = NO;

        void (^bufferHandler)() = ^{
            if (!buffering)
            {
                for (id val in bufferedValues)
                {
                    [subscriber sendNext:val];
                }

                [bufferedValues removeAllObjects];
            }
        };

        RACDisposable* bufferDisposable = [shouldBuffer subscribeNext:^(NSNumber* shouldBuffer) {

            buffering = shouldBuffer.boolValue;
            bufferHandler();

        }];

        if (bufferDisposable)
        {
            [disposable addDisposable:bufferDisposable];
        }

        RACDisposable* valueDisposable = [self subscribeNext:^(id x) {

            [bufferedValues addObject:x];
            bufferHandler();

        } error:^(NSError *error) {
            [subscriber sendError:error];
        } completed:^{
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];

        if (valueDisposable)
        {
            [disposable addDisposable:valueDisposable];
        }

        return disposable;
    }];
}

@end
```

Lastly, this is pseudo-code for how it would be used:

```
@interface APIManager ()

@property (nonatomic) RACSubject* requests;

@end

@implementation WebsocketDataLayer

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        RACSignal* connectedSignal = RACObserve(self, connected);

        self.requests = [[RACSubject alloc] init];

        RACSignal* bufferedApiRequests = [self.requests bufferWithSignal:connectedSignal];

        [self rac_liftSelector:@selector(sendRequest:) withSignalsFromArray:@[bufferedApiRequests]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)enqueueRequest:(NSString*)request
{
    [self.requests sendNext:request];
}

- (void)sendRequest:(NSString*)request
{
    DebugLog(@"Making websocket request: %@", request);
}

@end
```

My question is: Is this the right approach for buffering values? Is there a more idiomatic RAC way of handling this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Buffering can be thought of as something that applies to *individual* requests, which leads to a natural implementation using `-flattenMap:` and `RACObserve`:

```
@weakify(self);
RACSignal *bufferedRequests = [self.requests flattenMap:^(NSString *request) {
    @strongify(self);

    // Waits for self.connected to be YES, or checks that it already is,
    // then forwards the request.
    return [[[[RACObserve(self, connected)
        ignore:@NO]
        take:1]
        // Replace the property value with our request.
        mapReplace:request];
}];
```

If ordering is important, you can replace `-flattenMap:` with `-map:` plus `-concat`. These implementations avoid the need for any custom operators, and work without manual subscriptions (which are notoriously messy).

Comment: The `map` + `concat` option will be something like this if I'm not mistaken: https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/0d98e1058a83e5d7034cdda79fa5ec5f8b0bb780/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/UIRefreshControl%2BRACCommandSupport.m#L42

Comment: Excellent answer. Just for curiosity: isn't this a little too wasteful for higher throughput buffering? Can this be the reason why bufferWithTime: was not implemented in terms of this approach?

Comment: @allprog It might be a _little_ slower than an implementation like `-bufferWithTime:`, but it shouldn't be noticeable. It could be optimized by pulling the `RACObserve` out and using `-replayLast` upon it. Note also that `-bufferWithTime:` guarantees to send the _entire_ buffer once the period is up (introducing additional complexity, especially around completion), whereas that's not really important here.

Comment: Very cool!  I had a feeling there must be a way a "native" RAC way of handling this.  At first glance, this felt wasteful because of the repeated creation of the `self.connected` RACSignal.  However, I guess the RACDisposable semantics of `take:` handle the cleanup?

Comment: @MattHupman I'd start off by not worrying about it. If you _do_ begin to notice a performance issue, though, you can do as I mentioned above: move the `RACObserve` out of the block, and call `-replayLast` on it. This will ensure that the KVO observation only happens _once_, and subscribers will share all of the values from that one.

Answer (score 0):

You do almost exactly the same as what is implemented in the [`bufferWithTime:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/cbc263d04eb61519591e902a801d1ea74f405c4c/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.m#L315) operation and I can't think of any existing operations that would implement it more idiomatically. (Probably this is the reason why `bufferWithTime` was implemented in this way.) Reviewing your code using that implementation may reveal some faults you didn't think of.

But to be honest, this should not be so hard. There should exist a buffering operation that buffers the output and spews the contents when the trigger signal fires. Probably most buffering can be implemented in terms of this functionality, so having it would add value to the framework.